# How to work with Choices in Django - How to display specific content?

Tags: python, django

I try to create a book database in Django. I have to do one more thing. So i have a model with CHOICES:

```
#model Book
```

class Book(models.Model):

```
#book types and placed
BIOGRAPHY = 1
FANTASY = 2
HISTORICAL = 3
HORROR = 4
CLASSIC = 5
YOUTH_LITHERATURE = 6
NON_FICTION = 7
MODERN_LITERATURE = 8
POETRY = 9
ADVENTURE = 10
ESSAYS = 11
ROMANCE = 12
SATIRE = 13
THRILLER = 14
DRAMA = 15
NONE = 0

B00K_CHOICES = (
    (BIOGRAPHY,'Biography'),
    (FANTASY, 'Fantasy/Sci-Fi'),
    (HISTORICAL, 'Historical'),
    (HORROR, 'Horror'),
    (CLASSIC, 'Classic'),
    (YOUTH_LITHERATURE, 'Youth Litherature'),
    (NON_FICTION, 'Non-Fiction'),
    (MODERN_LITERATURE, 'Modern Literature'),
    (POETRY, 'Poetry'),
    (ADVENTURE, 'Adventure'),
    (ESSAYS, 'Essays'),
    (ROMANCE, 'Romance'),
    (SATIRE, 'Satire'),
    (THRILLER, 'Thriller'),
    (DRAMA, 'Drama'),
    (NONE, 'No Information'),
)




book_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='book_image', blank=True, null=True)
book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
book_author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
book_types = models.IntegerField(choices=B00K_CHOICES, default= NONE)
book_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
book_pages = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
book_published = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
book_ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='book', default=NONE)


def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.book_name)
```

And i create a simple view with display this choices:

```
def book_types_list(request):
book = Book.objects.all()
context = {'book': book, 'book_types': Book.B00K_CHOICES}
return render(request, 'plibrary_core/book_types_list.html', context)
```

I create also a html template with list of this choices:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block custom %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/background_color_styles.css' %}">
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}

<title>Book Types List | Private Library</title>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">

        <div class="col">
            <div id="background-color-content">
                <h3>Book Types</h3>
                <hr>

               {% for book_type in book_types %}
                    <ul>
                            <h6><a href="#">{{ book_type }}</a></h6>
                    </ul>
                {% endfor %}


            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And in this moment, i need to have something like this - User click on the book type (for example Horror) and then he see another template with all books with only this types. I try to do something like this but it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. Somebody know what i need to do?;X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firt use `ul` apropiatelly, with each item in a `li` tag, and in the correct place:

```
<ul> <!-- ul is outside the loop -->
{% loop %}
  <li> ...</li>
{% endloop %}
</ul>
```

Then in your view you don't need to call the object `Book.objects.all()` unless you want to show all your books. It looks like you are just displaying the book *choices*.

```
def book_types_list(request):
    book = Book.objects.all() # why do you need this in your view?
    context = {'book': book, 'book_types': Book.B00K_CHOICES}
    return render(request, 'foo/books.html', context)
```

Then in your template you just need to:

```
<ul>
    {% for book_type in book_types %}
    <li>
        <!-- you have to handle the logic of the url here -->
        <a href="{% url 'my_url' book_type.0 %}">{{ book_type.1 }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^my_url/(?P<book_type_id>\d+)/$', my_view, name='my_url'),
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Okay, so at this moment i see that when i click on the book type then i move in to the next page (404 but i see the number of choice). So in this moment what i need to do when i wan't to see every book in this choice on the next page? I mean - what view and url i need to pass it.

Comment: @Sparrowekk Don't take my code too literally. I will edit to be more clear. I put `a href="{{ book_type.0 }}">` as an example, because here you have to provide your logic, the url an the view that manages that url.

Comment: Ahh! I'm dumb! Okay, so i create a new view in this moment:      https://pastebin.com/hbA8ZcNR   and i add my logic to a href:   https://pastebin.com/t5Y3XcBZ  then i add the new url:  to display every type of book but i do something wrong:                                                          path('list/book/types/details/<int:book_types.id>/', views.book_types_detail, name='book_types_detail'),      It's something with view? Or meaby URL?

Comment: It's not {% url 'book_types_list:book_types_detail' **book_type.id** %} but **book_type.0**. book_type is not a model object.

Comment: Okay, i do this. I modified it to                                                                            <a href="{% url 'book_types_list:book_types_detail' book_type.0 %}">{{ book_type.1 }}</a> but i think is something wrong with my view or path. When i click on my type list then i have Reverse for 'book_types_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found error.

Comment: You have to think a little in your logic. The argument *book_type.0* is not the *pk* of `Book`, but the *type*. You use this to get a **list** of books with that type, not a single book, so don't use get_object_or_404. So something like this: `Book.objects.filter(book_type=book_types_id)`.

Comment: Mr Guillermo, Everything works! Thank You very much! Now my app have this what i need! :D You are a master of Django! :D

Comment: @Sparrowekk Haha. Not by far. Mark the question as useful for users that might find it helpful.

Comment: Yes, i do this few minutes ago :D Thank You very much!

Comment: Mr Guillermo, another little question. When i wan't to display my Book Type name in book_type_detail template (i see book_name only), i need to add another logic in my book_type_detail view?:P

Comment: No need. The object book has all the fields of the model. `book.book_types` should d the trick. I'd recommend that you read the documentation, so you not only will advance faster, but also find new techniques to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

with this element you get to render a select element on screen, and it will use the choices you are providing in choices, use that instead of the for loop of book types

```
{{ book.booktypes }}
```

Comment: When i use it instead of the for loop, Nothing is displayed (i change book_types instead booktypes).